# Drupal 8 cannot login after domain name change?

Tags: authentication, yaml, drupal-8

I have done simple Drupal 8 installation and while developing was accessing it via it's IP address, now when trying to log in as admin on the actual domain, every time after processing correct credentials it throws "Access Denied".

Google reveals this should be cookie_domain related issue. Tried changing the setting in services.yml to no avail, drush cr not helping. Either the issue is unrelated or the YML settings are not being picked up. Tried VM reboot since to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Have u checked the clean URL's enable on your site?
Try login your website from the URL: http://www.example.com/?q=user/login

Also I have noticed you have Drush installed. So use the drush for one time login link for user.

eg: [drush uli](https://drushcommands.com/drush-8x/user/user-login/)

Hope this helps you.